# MYSQL - Sum Rows by datetime after joining two tables

Tags: mysql, datetime

Thank you for looking at my question.

I am trying to sum the subtotal column and group by datetime via mysql. I have to join two tables, prior to the sum.

My first table, Payments, contains the following data:

```
ID | User_ID | Order_ID | Subtotal | Tax | Tip | Discount | Total | Payment_Method | Payment_Collected
12 | 123     |    76    | 10.99    | 0.99|  1  | 0.00     | 12.98 | Cash           |    1
```

My second table, Order, contains the following data:

```
ID | User_ID | Address_ID |    orderplaced_ts    | order_status
76 |   23    |     123    | 2015-02-26 12:23:41  |
```

The query that I tried to run is as follows:

```
select `order`.orderplaced_ts, SUM(`payments`.subtotal) as Subtotal
from `payments`
join `order` on `order`.id=`payments`.order_id
where `order`.order_status != "Cancelled"
and `payments`.payment_collected = 1
group by `order`.orderplaced_ts
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get all the sum of all subtotals and grouped by the same datetime. Sample output would be:

```
orderplaced_ts   |  Subtotal
 2015-02-20      |   123.12
 2015-02-21      |   223.12
 2015-02-22      |   124.25
 2015-02-23      |   247.23
 2015-02-24      |   623.50
```

My current query output is:

```
 orderplaced_ts       |  Subtotal
 2015-02-20 05:56:23  |   123.12
 2015-02-20 06:36:23  |   123.12
 2015-02-20 06:38:23  |   123.12
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction of why my query isn't giving me the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a formatted date to get rid of the time.
I think this would do what you want (not tested):

```
select date_format(`order`.orderplaced_ts,"%Y-%m-%d"), SUM(`payments`.subtotal) as Subtotal
from `payments`
join `order` on `order`.id=`payments`.order_id
where `order`.order_status != "Cancelled"
and `payments`.payment_collected = 1
group by date_format(`order`.orderplaced_ts,"%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: You could also use the more simple `DATE()` function like `GROUP BY DATE(\`order\`.orderplaced_ts)`, which I'm guessing, is also a tad faster.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that. I wasn't aware of that solution which is smarter than mine.